# How do I convert a str into an array (not a list) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, list, element

I'm trying to create an array from a string that is separated into different words, each of which would be a separate element. The split() works fine here, however, the string is stored as a list in the array. How do I store a string into an array such that each word will be its own element in the array and not a list?

```
var myArray = [];
var string = "Hello, my name is Cameron and I like turtles."
myArray.push(input.split(" "));

console.log(myArray.indexOf('name'));  //-1
console.log((myArray[0]));             //prints string in list
console.log((myArray[1]));             //undefined
console.log((myArray[2]));             //undefined
```

Comment: `split` itself returns an array. There is no need to create another array: `var myArray = input.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

this should work :

```
var string = "Hello, my name is Cameron and I like turtles."
var myArray = string.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are `push`ing an array *into another array*. You can initialize the value with the `split`ted string directly.

```
var string =  "Hello, my name is Cameron and I like turtles.",
    myArray = string.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var string =  "Hello, my name is Cameron and I like turtles.";
    var toArray = string.split("");

    console.log(toArray();//Will Display string as array
</script>
```

Here you go

Answer (score 0):

So you've created an array and string, that's fine.

```
var myArray = [];
var string = "Hello, my name is Cameron and I like turtles."
```

Now you're splitting the string and pushing the result of that to your first array.

```
myArray.push(input.split(" "));
```

This is where I think you're going wrong. You need to add the results to your original array, however you are adding them all as one item and in turn creating a multidimensional array.

You can either override your array:

```
myArray = input.split(" ")
```

Or concat them. This might be a better approach if you need to do it multiple times.

```
myArray.concat(input.split(" "));
```